# Python: date, time formatting

Tags: python, datetime

I need to generate a local timestamp in a form of YYYYMMDDHHmmSSOHH'mm'. That OHH'mm' is one of +, -, Z and then there are hourhs and minutes followed by '.

Please, how do I get such a timestamp, denoting both local time zone and possible daylight saving?

Comment: Where did you look for time formatting?  What did you try?  What errors did you get?

Comment: I read std lib docs, and they are confusing what timezones goes...

Comment: "confusing"?  Could mean anything.  To help others with the same problem, could you provide the quote or link that confused you?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
import time

localtime   = time.localtime()
timeString  = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", localtime)

# is DST in effect?
timezone    = -(time.altzone if localtime.tm_isdst else time.timezone)
timeString += "Z" if timezone == 0 else "+" if timezone > 0 else "-"
timeString += time.strftime("%H'%M'", time.gmtime(abs(timezone)))
```

Comment: This just got me "20100321142049-01'00'" :)

Comment: Oh, no! There is a bug. Say, someone lives in Italy, the timezone then is +01'00', not -01'00'...

Comment: In docs, there is an examle and there they say "-time.altzone" and "-time.timezone". Hmm....

Comment: For complete noob's like me.. don't forget to "import time" first

Comment: @khylo There you go, sorry :)

Comment: `utc_offset = -(time.altzone if time.daylight and time.localtime().tm_isdst > 0 else time.timezone)` or if you need a string: `time.strftime('%z')`

Answer (score 8):

[time.strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) will do for that,

And in linux, `%z` will just give you -HHMM format if environment variable is properly set.

```
>>> os.environ['TZ'] = 'EST'
>>> time.strftime('%x %X %z')
'03/21/10 08:16:33 -0500'
```

Comment: How? There is no way how to get timezone offset, and %Z gets just the timezone name..?

Comment: @TarGz - time.timezone has offset of localtime zone in secs, you may want to combine two to make it work

Comment: It seems, %z is pltaform dependent

Comment: @TarGz, yeah, its need time.tzset(), and its only available in Unix

Comment: @TarGz it's a lowercase z.