# In Python, how to display current time in readable format

Tags: python, datetime, time

How can I display the current time as:

```
12:18PM EST on Oct 18, 2010
```

in Python.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be helpful to extend the database of questions & answers on the site.  No such question had been asked before.

Comment: @ensnare: Every one of these appears to already answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+time+format.  Are you suggesting that there's something distinctive about your question?  If so, what makes your question unique?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: date, time formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487109/python-date-time-formatting)

Comment: @S.Lott, I apologize, I didn't see that last link.

Comment: @ensnare Don't apologise mate, SO is TFM! Almost every question and answer has subtle and valuable differences. The more questions the better.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

First the quick and dirty way, and second the precise way (recognizing daylight's savings or not).

```
import time
time.ctime() # 'Mon Oct 18 13:35:29 2010'
time.strftime('%l:%M%p %Z on %b %d, %Y') # ' 1:36PM EDT on Oct 18, 2010'
time.strftime('%l:%M%p %z on %b %d, %Y') # ' 1:36PM EST on Oct 18, 2010'
```

Comment: `%z` produces offset e.g., `-0400`. `%Z` gives you current timezone name (or abbreviation) automatically. Python doesn't support `%l`, you could use `%I` instead.

Comment: %Z gives me "Eastern Time Zone" how can I get the abbreviation of 'est' or 'EST'

Answer (score 49):

All you need is [in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html).

```
import time
time.strftime('%X %x %Z')
'16:08:12 05/08/03 AEST'
```

Answer (score 17):

By using this code, you'll get your live time zone.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print ("Current date and time : ")
print (now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Answer (score 11):

```
import time
time.strftime('%H:%M%p %Z on %b %d, %Y')
```

[This may come in handy](http://strftime.org/)

Comment: The output looks like this: "01:57AM UTC on Oct 27, 2022"

Answer (score 8):

You could do something like:

```
>>> from time import gmtime, strftime
>>> strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime())
'Thu, 28 Jun 2001 14:17:15 +0000'
```

The full doc on the % codes are at http://docs.python.org/library/time.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the facilities provided by the [`time`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) module

You have several conversion functions there.

**Edit:** see the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module for more OOP-like solutions. The `time` library linked above is kinda imperative.