# Displaying the time

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, codeskulptor

So, using this website i have come up with the following code:

```
import time
print(time.strftime('%l:%M%p %Z on %b %d %Y'))
#' 1:36PM EDT on Oct 18, 2010'
print("time done")
time.sleep(5)
```

From the following sources: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961581/in-python-how-to-display-current-time-in-readable-format),[2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html)

For some reason though, this code doesn't work.

I'm trying to get the time to show similar to the comment, although if I could get the seconds in as well that would be good.
I also tried this:

```
import time
print time.strftime("%l"+":"+"%M"+"%p"+ "%Z"+ "%b"+ "%d"+ "%Y")
#' 1:36PM EDT on Oct 18, 2010'
print("time done")
time.sleep(5)
```

but it doesn't work either.

EDIT: Error I get even from `print(time.strftime('%l:%M:%S%p %Z on %b %d, %Y'))`:

```
AttributeError: '<invalid type>' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

EDIT2: for those that don't believe me: !The error and code in CodeSkulptor] https://www.dropbox.com/s/joyxsod8yv899fm/THERE.png

I used python 3.3.3 and codeskulptor

Comment: Concatenating the components still builds the exact same string format, so that makes *no* difference.

Comment: Your error would *not* have `<invalid type>` there; it would be `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'` or `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'strftime'` or similar. You most likely rebound `time` to something else.

Answer (score 1):

All you forgot was a comma after `%d`:

```
>>> print(time.strftime('%l:%M%p %Z on %b %d, %Y'))
 7:06PM GMT on Dec 14, 2013
```

Adding in seconds means you want to insert `%S` somewhere:

```
>>> print(time.strftime('%l:%M:%S%p %Z on %b %d, %Y'))
 7:07:47PM GMT on Dec 14, 2013
```

Note that CodeSkulptor does *not* support the `time` module very well. Code using `time.strftime()` on CodeSkulptor will fail, but that is hardly a Python problem. Even a base `print(time.strftime())` call fails.

Comment: Also, the author forget parenthesis in his example at the first print (he's using Python 3.x)

Comment: Still gives an error, see edited question

Comment: @L0neGamer: You rebound `time` to another value, somewhere. `time = ...` replaces the module.

Comment: Proof of error, no idea what's wrong

Comment: @L0neGamer: That is a *codeskulptor* problem only.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes it was. For people who look upon this post in the future, replace the apostrophes in Martijn's solution above with speech marks - but for some reason the seconds thing doesn't work

Comment: @L0neGamer: you could [post your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to make your comment more visible.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Not within 8 hrs!

Comment: @L0neGamer: I am not sure what you mean by speech marks here. The code, as posted, works in any normal Python 3 interpreter. Online Python sites may or may not be able to run the code.