# How to format time for display in flask?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am trying to display time in `10:34 PM` format but MySQL server has it in `22:34:00` format. I tried to do `{{ invoice['time'].strftime("%I:%M %p") }}` but I am getting error saying `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'datetime.timedelta object' has no attribute 'strftime'`

I also tried to convert it to string then just get the first 5 character hoping to give at least `22:34` format but it also failed. `{{ invoice['time']|string[:5] }}`

How to achieve this? The MySQL stores it in time and not datetime.

Comment: With MySql you can do: `select time(now()), time_format(time(now()),'%H:%i');`, which gives (now): `17:16:28     17:16`. Or, if you want to do it in python, see: [In Python, how to display current time in readable format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961581/in-python-how-to-display-current-time-in-readable-format)

Comment: I would maybe tweak the SQL a bit. If you have a time you probably have a date too (in a separate field). You could concatenate both values to produce an expression column that will be rendered as datetime instead of timedelta.