# Dropping zeros at the end 12:00:00

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have the following code:

```
    Now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    print(datetime.time(Now.hour, Now.minute))
```

I want to modify the following outputs from having the zeros at the end:

```
    12:53:00  ->  12:53
    06:19:00  ->  06:19
```

If you know how to fix that thanks in advance for your answer.
By the way I have looked at other questions asked but none worked with this particular case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: date, time formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487109/python-date-time-formatting)

Comment: I have seen that question earlier and tested the solutions but none worked.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Well if I use the answer from the other question it dosent show the time of my computer and therefore I am forced to use "datetime" but I am not very good at formatting and need help formatting it so it removes the zeros at the end.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) on the `time` object:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
print(now.strftime('%H:%M'))
```

Using this method you can format the `time` object in the way that would want without the seconds.