# Rounding off date time now

Tags: python, datetime

Hi people I am new to python. I'm developing a port scanner and need the start time and the time it took to complete the scan. I have manged to do this, however I want the time format as 12.58.32   when I use the time.datetimenow() I get the milli seconds printed. I dont want this. Can anyone help please? I know how to get the time taken to scan.   t1 - t2 = scanTime. I just want it rounded of to seconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: date, time formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487109/python-date-time-formatting)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this. This will give you **only current time** without microsecond in **string format**.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H.%M.%S")
```

If you want to convert this string in `datetime` object then you can also try like this and then extract time as your wish.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S"), "%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

Write generic function to get current time:

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_current_time():
   """ Current time"""
   time_format = "%H.%M.%S"
   time = datetime.now().strftime(time_format)
   return datetime.strptime(time, time_format)
```

Now calculate t1 and t2 as per your need:

```
t1 = get_current_time()
t2 = get_current_time()
# Get time difference
scan_time = t2 - t1
# Convert time into seconds
total_seconds = scan_time.total_seconds()
```

Hope it will help.